# Magento Product Review Form in a Popup

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I removed the Review form from the product page, because i use a extension which sent the customer an email with a link to specific url with a review form for products they bought.

But i need a more or less hidden page (www.shop.com/productname/review) with the review form, if i sold a product out of the shop.

I use Magento 1.6

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are a little familiar with the inner workings of Magento, as this is definitely not for beginners :).

First, you need to start by observing the `controller_front_init_router` event, like so:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <controller_front_init_routers>
            <observers>
                <controller_noroute>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Module_Controller_Router</class>
                    <method>initControllerRouters</method>
                </controller_noroute>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_init_routers>
    </events>
</global>
```

Now, if you've been around development, you'll notice that I am going a little unconventional here by using a controller as an observer. To me it cleans things up a little bit. But, who knows, there might be a better way to do it?

Here is the controller. As you can see, we have effectively inserted our router to the end of the router match list (just before the `default` router if you look at `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front`).

```
class Namespace_Module_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Abstract
{
    public function initControllerRouters($observer)
    {
        /* @var $front Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front */
        $front = $observer->getFront();

        $front->addRouter('Namespace_Module', $this);
    }

    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request) {
        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');

        $parts = explode("/", $identifier);
        if (count($parts) > 1) {
            $productKey = $parts[0];
            $action = $parts[1];

            if (count($parts) > 2 && (count($parts)%2) == 0) {
                for ($i = 2; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
                    $request->setParam($parts[$i], $parts[$i++]);
                }
            }

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute($productKey, 'url_key');
            if ($product->getId()) {
                $request->setModuleName('your_module')
                    ->setControllerName('index')
                    ->setActionName($action);

                $request->setAlias(Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $identifier);

                return true;
            } else {
                // Redirect to an error.
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: You are right, this is nothing for beginner :|

Comment: Remember to mark this as an answer if it answered your question.

Comment: I would, but i am not a developer and can't implement it. :(

Comment: That's strange. The [faq] never mentions anywhere that you must be a developer to accept answers. Try rolling your mouse over the checkmark for a second or two, it doesn't mention anything about that there either.

Comment: @bassplayer7 your are funny. How do i know if this works, if i can't test it.